# Challenges in using flat memory model

Tags: embedded, real-time, cpu, paging, memory-model

The flat memory model(linear memory model) provides maximum execution speed, occupies minimum CPU real estate and has direct access to memory without any segmentation / paging. It seems that flat memory model is ideal for small realtime application or single threaded realtime application.
However, is it possible to use real-time application that is multi-threaded/multi-tasking along with requirement of high resource allocation/protection in flat memory model ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, the concern is on bringing in the requirement of memory protection part.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the memory model has much to do here, except for the (RT)OS itself which you use to get multi-threading / multi-tasking done.

Paging or segmentation, if provided, is useful for the OS primarily for implementing memory protection features. It is only possible this way that the OS may protect itself and running user mode tasks against improperly written code in others which would accidentally write in memory out of their intended domain. (You can't get memory protection without some kind of paging or segmentation since you can't guard every single memory access)

In 32 bit AVR processors there is even a distinction between *Memory management unit* (MMU) and *Memory protection unit* (MPU). The first is the more complex unit supporting those kinds of paging features like modern PC processors (for example even making it possible to realize virtual memory), while the latter is a simpler subset only giving you tools for realizing memory protection (for example by the OS, to protect itself and tasks against each other), while it does not have any remapping capability (by a given address you always access the same cell of memory) like the MMU does. (Why the distinction? Because some cheaper AVR32's, where that's sufficient, only have an MPU)

So on a simple flat memory model what important thing you won't get are the protection features. If you can get by without those, it should go just fine.